# Play youtube embed url in videoview

Tags: android

I have some youtube embed url [youtube video url](https://www.youtube.com/embed/fRGbPvHm2dU)

I want to play this url in android video view. I tried it,but everytime its shows cannot play this video dialog.

Anyone can help me to play embed video in videoview.

Answer (score 0):

For playing youtube video in Videoview you need rtsp url.
I think to play youtube video use youtube api. Follow this url it will helpful
http://javatechig.com/android/youtubeplayerview-example-in-android-using-youtube-api

Comment: I have embed url,rtsp i know it is possible.Can you please give me solution to play youtube  embed url.

Comment: Is it possible to play youtube video (embed) in android videoview?